# Struggling to understand python package and import statment

Tags: python

I have a package like this

```
sound/
    __init__.py
   effects/
       __init__.py
       echo.py
   formats/
      __init__.py
     avi.py
```

inside avi.py  i have import statement like this

```
from sound.effects import echo
```

this code throws **No Module Named sound.effect** error

From  the [pythondocs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) i understood that this is possible. And I am search through stackoverflow
and found related question and answers, but I couldn't understand them.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks,

Prawyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running `avi.py` from the `formats` folder, and don't adjust your `PYTHONPATH`, Python won't be able to find the `effects` package. Try running your code from outside the sounds directory, modifying your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable such that it includes the directory in which `sound` lives is part of thtat, or changing your `PYTHONPATH` at runtime (see e.g. [this link](http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I am running avi.py form formats folder. Will go through the link and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the folder name is `effects`, why are you trying to import from `effect`? Try `from sound.effects import echo` instead.

Also, why are you trying to import `echo` from within itself?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. I changed question. I have to import echo into avi

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `sound.effect` is a typo and is `sound.effects`. If that's the case, then the issue is likely due to your project structure.

If the root level of your project is `sound` as in your diagram and you've added it to your `PYTHONPATH` (or any number of other installation methods), then Python won't know where to look for `sound` (as there's no directory relative to your root directory named `sound`).

So, generally you'll see package structures such as:

```
sound/
    README
    LICENSE
    setup.py
    sound/
        __init__.py
```

...And so on.

With your current directory structure (and if my assumption is correct), then the import that will actually work is `from effects import echo`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my question. Sorry .

Comment: Same problem: Python still won't know what the root ``sound`` package is. Try changing your ``import`` statement in ``avi.py`` to ``from effects import echo`` as a quick test to see if my assumption is correct.